# When should a covered call option be bought back to avoid assignment

Tags: united-states, options, covered-call-writing

I am trying to learn options.  I sold a covered call (weekly option) that will  expire on October 25th  and I want to avoid being assigned.

Should I buy it back on 24th (one day early) or can it be bought back on the 25th (the day of expiration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can trade equity options until   4 PM EST on the day of expiration.

Should you buy it back depends on whether it is in- or out-of-the money (and by how much), as well as whether you plan to write calls for a later expiration.